# Finding difference between two rows with a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my data frame`df`, which has 3 variables and approx 100k data points,

```
   ID   A   B   C
   1    35  0   0
   2    28  0   0
   3    36  0   0
   4    99  0   0 
   5    25  1   0
   6    65  1   0
   7    98  1   0
   8    95  1   0
   9    67  0   65
  10    95  0   65 
  11    94  1   65
  12    4   0   65
  13    2   -1  0
  14    62  -1  0
  15    95  -1  0
  16    25  -1  0
  17    36  0   19.5
  18    3   0   19.5
  20    68  1   19.5     
  21    17  0   0
```

Now, I would like to create another variables `D` which contains the difference between the Last data point of `A` where `B == 1 or -1`and the immediate next value in `C` where `B == 1 or -1`.

Another condition is that if the value in the column `C` is same for the next 4 values as then the program should not consider to subtract the values `A` and `C` Eg, `B11 ==1` it has the change of value to 1 but program should not consider that data point to find the difference between `A11 and C12` because value of `C` is still within the count of 4 when `B` has changed. Similarly for the Data point at `B20`.

**Expected Output**

```
    ID  A   B   C       D
     1  35  0   0       0
     2  28  0   0       0
     3  36  0   0       0
     4  99  0   0       0
     5  25  1   0       0
     6  65  1   0       0
     7  98  1   0       0
     8  95  1   0       30
     9  67  0   65      0
    10  95  0   65      0
    11  94  1   65      0
    12  4   0   65      0
    13  2   -1  0       0
    14  62  -1  0       0
    15  95  -1  0       0
    16  25  -1  0      5.5
    17  36  0   19.5    0
    18  3   0   19.5    0  
    19  5   0   19.5    0  
    20  68  1   19.5    0 
    21  17  0   0       0
```

Comment: According to your 1st rule, the first 4 values for D should be  `NA`.  And the 5th should be 25-0 = 25.  You should reexplain your rules, I find them really obscure.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, My 1st condition never tells about having `NA` in the first 4 values, also I have mentioned clearly that I need difference between last data point of `A` where `B==1 or -1` and first data point in `c` after which `B==1 or -1`. Well 5th is not the last data point of `A` where `B == 1 or -1`, rather its 8th.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

**condition 1:**

```
# create a list of instances where B == 1:
B_one <- which(x$B == 1)

# fill the D column with 0
x$D <- rep(0, nrow(x))  

# In cases where B == 1 then overwrite with the difference between A_n and C_n+1
for (i in c(1:length(B_one))){
    x[B_one[i], "D"] <- x[B_one[i], "A"] - x[B_on[(i+1)], "C"]  
}
```

**condition 2 (and I may have misinterpreted this bit):**

```
# Create a list which counts how many times C has repeated
counter <- sequence(rle(as.character(x$C))$lengths)

# In cases where this is <= 4 then overwrite again
x[counter <= 4, "D"] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. You can collapse a few steps if you want to:

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                         11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L), A = c(35L, 
                                                                                                  28L, 36L, 99L, 25L, 65L, 98L, 95L, 67L, 95L, 94L, 4L, 2L, 62L, 
                                                                                                  95L, 25L, 36L, 3L, 68L, 17L), B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                      1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), C = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 65, 65, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.5, 19.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     19.5, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -20L)))

getGroups <- function(x){
  grouplengths <- rle(x)$lengths
  return(rep(1:length(grouplengths),grouplengths))
}

getLastValue <- function(x){
  return(c(rep(0,length(x)-1),x[length(x)]))
}

mydt[,Bgroup:=getGroups(B)]
mydt[B %in% c(1,-1),Bpresent:=TRUE]
mydt[is.na(Bpresent),Bpresent:=FALSE]
mydt[Bpresent==TRUE,lastA:=A[.N],by=Bgroup]
mydt[Bpresent==TRUE,firstC:=ifelse(sum(Bpresent)<4,C[1],0),by=Bgroup]
mydt[Bpresent==TRUE,difference:=lastA-shift(firstC,type="lead")]
mydt[is.na(difference)|(lastA==difference),difference:=0]
mydt[,c("Bgroup","Bpresent","lastA","firstC"):=NULL]
mydt
# ID  A  B    C difference
# 1:  1 35  0  0.0        0.0
# 2:  2 28  0  0.0        0.0
# 3:  3 36  0  0.0        0.0
# 4:  4 99  0  0.0        0.0
# 5:  5 25  1  0.0        0.0
# 6:  6 65  1  0.0        0.0
# 7:  7 98  1  0.0        0.0
# 8:  8 95  1  0.0       30.0
# 9:  9 67  0 65.0        0.0
# 10: 10 95  0 65.0        0.0
# 11: 11 94  1 65.0        0.0
# 12: 12  4  0 65.0        0.0
# 13: 13  2 -1  0.0        0.0
# 14: 14 62 -1  0.0        0.0
# 15: 15 95 -1  0.0        0.0
# 16: 16 25 -1  0.0        5.5
# 17: 17 36  0 19.5        0.0
# 18: 18  3  0 19.5        0.0
# 19: 20 68  1 19.5        0.0
# 20: 21 17  0  0.0        0.0
```